# Java method to read text file and return ArrayList type object

Tags: java

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList <Locations>       LocationsList       = readFile("Locations.csv", "Locations");
        //ArrayList <Movies>          MoviesList          = readFile("Movies.csv", "Movies");
        //ArrayList <Operators>       OperatorsList       = readFile("Operators.csv", "Operators");
        //ArrayList <PersonCategory>  PersonCategoryList  = readFile("PersonCategory.csv", "PersonCategory");
    }
    
    public static ArrayList readFile(String fileName, String whichFile)
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            
            String indata;
            
            int line = 0;
            while((indata=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(indata,",");
                
                if(line != 0)
                {
                    if(whichFile.equals("Locations"))
                    {
                        int id = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                        String city = st.nextToken();
                        if(city.charAt(0) == '"')
                        {
                            String c = st.nextToken();
                            city = city.substring(1,city.length()) +"," +c.substring(0,c.length()-1);
                        }
                        int stateId = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                        
                        Locations x = new Locations(id, city, stateId);
                        list.add(x);
                    }
                    
                    else if(whichFile.equals("Movies"))
                    {
                        int id = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                        String name = st.nextToken();
                        int ratingId = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                        
                        Movies x = new Movies(id, name, ratingId);
                        list.add(x);
                    }                              
                }
                
                line++;
            }
            
            br.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());}
        catch (IOException io){System.out.println(io.getMessage());}
        catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
        
        return list;
    }
```

I'm trying to create a method that will read a text file and can return an ArrayList type object for the usage of multiple Class. With my code above, it can run successfully.

But, there are lines of warning like:
"The expression of type `ArrayList` needs unchecked conversion to conform to `ArrayList<Locations>`"

How do I fix this?

Comment: Make use of generics

Comment: Instead of passing the class name as String, you can pass it as Class type and make the method generic compatible

Comment: Is this a homework? The `Files` class has a method for this already https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the proper generics-based `ArrayList` using for example: `new ArrayList<Location>()`

You could solve this by passing a class to readFile like this:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> readFile(....., Class<T> clazz)
{
   ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
   ...
}
```

Comment: I've done what you showed above. But there is a line of error saying "The method add(T) in the type ArrayList<T> is not applicable for the arguments (Locations)" on the `list.add(x);` . How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> readFile(String fileName, Function<String[], T> converter) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName))) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        String[] fields = line.split(",");
        T object = converter.apply(fields);
        result.add(object);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and define the converters which convert a CSV line to an object.

```
static Locations convertLocations(String[] fields) {
    int id = Integer.parseInt(fields[0]);
    String city = fields[1];
    if (city.charAt(0) == '"') {
        String c = fields[2];
        city = city.substring(1, city.length()) + "," + c.substring(0, c.length() - 1);
    }
    int stateId = Integer.parseInt(fields[3]);
    Locations x = new Locations(id, city, stateId);
    return x;
}

static Movies convertMovies(String[] fields) {
    /* Make Movies object from fields */
}
```

and combine them.

```
ArrayList<Locations> LocationsList = readFile("Locations.csv", fields -> convertLocations(fields));
ArrayList<Movies> MoviesList = readFile("Movies.csv", fields -> convertMovies(fields));
```

Comment: Your idea looks nice but, I actually have 10 Classes that I need to use on the `readFile` method. Then, do I also need to create 10 convert methods? If yes, then I would like to know a different approach where I can make my code as short as possible.

Comment: Yes, you need to create 10 convert methods.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you need to specify the type parameter for generic class `ArrayList`.

Since you are adding objects created from different classes to the same list, you could create an interface, say, `MyInterface`

```java
public interface MyInterface {
    ....
}
```

All classes you return from `readFile` must implement this interface. For eg.

```java
public class Movies implements MyInterface {
    ....
}
```

Now, you can add type parameter `MyInterface` at appropriate places:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<MyInterface> LocationsList = readFile("Locations.csv", "Locations");
        ....
    }

public static ArrayList<MyInterface> readFile(String fileName, String whichFile) {
 
  ArrayList<MyInterface> list = new ArrayList<>();
            ....
        }
```

**Added below info based on reply**

You may in fact choose to leave the interface blank, but then you will have to explicitly cast objects to concrete classes to do anything useful.

1. You could cast each object when needed

```
        MyInterface myInterfaceObject = locationsList.get(0)
        Locations locations = Locations.class.cast(myInterfaceObject);
```

OR

```
        MyInterface myInterfaceObject = locationsList.get(0)
        Locations locations = (Locations) myInterfaceObject;
```

2. OR You could write a list converter function for each concrete type

```
public class ListConverter {
  public ArrayList<Locations> toLocationsArraylist(ArrayList<MyInterface> inList) {
      ArrayList<Locations> outList = new ArrayList<>();
      for (MyInterface listItem : inList) {
          outList.add((Locations) listItem);
      }
      return outList;
  }
}
```

and then

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<MyInterface> myInterfaceList = readFile("Locations.csv", "Locations");
        ArrayList<Locations> locationList = ListConverter.toLocationsArraylist(myInterfaceList);
       
    }
```

If you do consider using this solution, then consider renaming MyInterface more appropriately, say, to `CsvRecord`, or anything domain-specific.

Comment: I'm sorry but, I am not familiar with the usage of interface. Can you explain in detail on what do I have to write in the `MyInterface`?

Comment: @AmarKou You can think of an interface as a contract or a type. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here. I am editing my answer with one of the possible ways.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final code that I took from @saka1029 and made some adjustments so that it will read every line in the file except the first one.

```
    public static <T> ArrayList<T> readFile(String fileName, Function<String[], T> converter)
    {
        ArrayList <T> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            br.readLine();
            
            String inData;
            
            while((inData=br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] fields = inData.split(",");
                T object = converter.apply(fields);
                list.add(object);
            }
            
            br.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());}
        catch (IOException io){System.out.println(io.getMessage());}
        catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
        
        return list;
    }
```

And this is my version of the correction of the method `convertLocations` from @saka1029 answer.

```
    static Locations convertLocations(String[] fields)
    {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(fields[0]);
        String city = fields[1];
        int stateId;
        if (city.charAt(0) == '"')
        {
            String c = fields[2];
            city = city.substring(1, city.length()) + "," + c.substring(0, c.length() - 1);
            stateId = Integer.parseInt(fields[3]);
        }
        else
            stateId = Integer.parseInt(fields[2]);
        
        Locations x = new Locations(id, city, stateId);
        
        return x;
    }
```